# How do I enable side-to-side touchpad scrolling navigation in Chromium on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, synaptics-touchpad, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Chromium version 70.0.3538.110 and Ubuntu 18.04. By default, there doesn't seem to be back/forward page navigation enabled to work with touchpad horizontal scrolling, which I would like to have.

I have seen suggestions to change this setting (chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation), but it doesn't seem to do anything when I try changing it and restarting my browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different flag called *Overscroll history navigation on Touchpad* that is not available on linux. Looking for a different option to mplement this as well

Comment: Do you mean Linux, not Linus?